# Modificar consulta linkedServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, linkedserver

Tengo una consulta que me está costando mucho sacar.
Actualmente tengo la siguiente consulta :

```
    USE [GCP]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[REPORTING_ADABAS_spDIFERENCIAS_LIQUIDACIONES_TIPO]    Script Date: 15/7/2020 12:02:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


--ASAMARAN 2011-07-06
--FMARTIPAR 2015-21-03 datetime to datetime2 para que registre como nulo las fechas del año 0100-01-01
-- rgonzals 20180418 Ajuste en filtro de estaciones para obtener los datos para castellana
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPORTING_ADABAS_spDIFERENCIAS_LIQUIDACIONES_TIPO]
    @empresa as tinyint,
    @fechaini as varchar(10),
    @fechafin as varchar(10),
    @liston as int=0
AS 
set nocount on;
DECLARE @idliq int
DECLARE @sLINKEDSERVER as varchar(100)
DECLARE @EmpresaFiltro int

IF (@empresa=1 OR @empresa=2) SET --@sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidaciones'
@sLINKEDSERVER = 'BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidaciones'
ELSE IF @empresa=4 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidacionesAumar'
ELSE IF @empresa=9 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidacionesAvasa'
ELSE IF @empresa=3 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_REPORTLIQUIDACIONESIBERPISTAS'
ELSE IF @empresa=11 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_REPORTLIQUIDACIONESIBERPISTAS'

IF(@empresa = 3) SET @EmpresaFiltro = 2
ELSE IF (@empresa = 11) SET @EmpresaFiltro = 11 

CREATE TABLE #tempLiqDif(
    ID_LIQUIDACION int, ID_DiaEstacion int, EstadoDiaEstacion varchar(4),
    Fecha datetime, Estacion varchar(10), Cobrador varchar(10),
    NumLiq varchar(10), Bolsa varchar(10),
    HoraInicio datetime2, HoraFin datetime2,
    CodigoMotivo varchar(15), DiferenciaMotivo decimal(18,2), NumDif tinyint,
    RecTeoricaPrevia decimal(18,2),RecTeoricaRevisada decimal(18,2),RecContada decimal(18,2)
)

DECLARE @sSQL varchar(2000)
SET @sSQL = '
INSERT INTO #tempLiqDif(ID_LIQUIDACION,id_diaestacion,EstadoDiaEstacion,Fecha,Estacion,numliq,Bolsa,horainicio,horafin,Cobrador,CodigoMotivo,DiferenciaMotivo,NumDif,RecTeoricaPrevia,RecTeoricaRevisada,RecContada)
               SELECT ID_LIQUIDACION,id_diaestacion,EstadoDiaEstacion,Fecha,Estacion,numliq,Bolsa,horainicio,horafin,Cobrador,CodigoMotivo,DiferenciaMotivo,NumDif,RecTeoricaPrevia,RecTeoricaRevisada,RecContada
FROM openquery('+@sLINKEDSERVER+',''
    SELECT l.id_liquidacion, d.id_diaestacion, d.diar_indestde as EstadoDiaEstacion, l.liqr_fecdiaex as Fecha, l.liqr_codestac as Estacion, 
        l.liqr_codliqui as numliq, l.liqr_codbolsa as Bolsa, l.liqr_horainiac as horainicio, l.liqr_horafinac as horafin, l.liqr_codigo as Cobrador,
        m.liqr_codmotdif as CodigoMotivo, m.Liqr_impfsdif*0.01 as DiferenciaMotivo, m.liqr_difcount as NumDif,
        l.liqr_impteor*0.01 as RecTeoricaPrevia, 
        (l.liqr_impptacn - (m.Liqr_impfsdif))*0.01 as RecTeoricaRevisada,
        l.liqr_impptacn*0.01 as RecContada
    FROM ((liquidaciones l 
        INNER JOIN diaestacion d ON d.diar_codestac = l.liqr_codestac and d.diar_fecdiaex = l.liqr_fecdiaex)
        INNER JOIN liq_dif m ON l.id_liquidacion = m.id_liquidacion and m.cnxarraycolumn = 1)
    WHERE l.liqr_tipliqui = ''''E'''' 
        AND (ABS(l.liqr_impptacn-l.liqr_impteor) * 0.01)>='+cast(@liston as varchar)+' 
        AND l.liqr_fecdiaex BETWEEN '''''+@fechaini+''''' And '''''+@fechafin+'''''
'')'

EXEC (@sSQL)

DECLARE rs cursor FAST_FORWARD for 
    SELECT ID_LIQUIDACION FROM #tempLiqDif
OPEN RS

CREATE TABLE #tempLiqVias(idliq int, via char(5), pos tinyint)

FETCH NEXT FROM rs INTO @idliq
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
    SET @sSQL = 'INSERT INTO #tempLiqVias(idliq, via, pos)
SELECT ID_LIQUIDACION, LIQR_VIA, cnxarraycolumn 
FROM openquery('+@sLINKEDSERVER+',''
SELECT v.ID_LIQUIDACION, LIQR_VIA, v.cnxarraycolumn FROM liq_vias v WHERE (v.cnxarraycolumn<4 or right(LIQR_VIA,1)=''''M'''') AND ID_LIQUIDACION='+ CAST(@idliq as varchar)+''')'
    EXEC (@sSQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM rs INTO @idliq
END
CLOSE RS
DEALLOCATE RS

select ge.ge_nombre Gerencia, es_nombre+'-'+es.Es_descripcion as EstacionDescripcion, v.liqvias as VIAS, dl.*
FROM #tempLiqDif dl
    left join (
SELECT idliq, Coalesce([0]+' ','')+Coalesce([1]+' ','')+Coalesce([2]+' ','')+Coalesce([3],'') as liqvias
FROM #tempLiqVias PIVOT ( MIN(via) FOR pos IN ([0],[1],[2],[3]) ) AS pvt
) v on v.idliq = dl.id_liquidacion
    join gcp.dbo.estaciones es on es.es_nombre = dl.Estacion collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
    join gcp.dbo.gerencias ge on ge_codigo = es_ge_codigo AND (@EmpresaFiltro IS NULL OR es.es_em_codigo = @EmpresaFiltro)  AND ((es.ES_FECHA_BAJA IS NULL AND es.ES_FECHA_ALTA < Fecha) OR es.ES_FECHA_BAJA > Fecha)
order by ge_nombre, estacion, fecha, horainicio
GO
```

Esta consulta funcionaba con Store procedure - Linked server:

Teniendo esta distribución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora lo he hecho en tablas. De tal forma que la distribución es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que modificar el código:

```
IF (@empresa=1 OR @empresa=2) SET --@sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidaciones'
@sLINKEDSERVER = 'BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidaciones'
ELSE IF @empresa=4 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidacionesAumar'
ELSE IF @empresa=9 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_ReportLiquidacionesAvasa'
ELSE IF @empresa=3 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_REPORTLIQUIDACIONESIBERPISTAS'
ELSE IF @empresa=11 SET @sLINKEDSERVER='BCNASTXSAP01_REPORTLIQUIDACIONESIBERPISTAS'
```

Pero voy algo perdida, podéis ayudarme?

Comment: Dado que ya no usas otros servidores, no es necesario que lances `OpenQuery`, simplemente haz la consulta, siempre con SQL dinámico y prefija los nombres de las tablas con el nombre del esquema correspondiente.

Comment: el problema es que no se si quitando el open query es suficiente. Y cuando dices prefijar puedes darme algun ejemplo? Gracias! Es que voy algo perdida y no quiero ir a saco borrando o cambiando cosas sin acabar de entender los motivos.

Comment: Creo que, antes de modificar el procedimiento almacenado, debieras hacer el ejercicio de escribir, a mano, el query para obtener la información de dos empresas distintas, digamos en el _Management Studio_. Una vez lo logres, creo que comprenderás fácilmente lo que cambia entre un query y otro. Otra sugerencia es que tomes el código del _SP_ y en lugar de ejecutar el query, imprimas el valor de la variable `@sSQL`. Creo que ocurre justamente que falta que profundices un poco en el tema y la pregunta es bastante amplia como está.